# Upgrading Context Broker FIware

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I tried to install Context Broker version 1.7.0 on my Centos 6 VM.
I successfully installed it but while the service is running ,when i make a request with curl i get the message "couldn't connect to host"
I checked the port 1026 and the firewall and everything is ok.
Any ideas what may be the problem?

Comment: Can you please share the output of the command `contextBroker --version` ? Also an output of your curl command run with -vv switch would be helpful.

Comment: $ contextBroker --version
1.7.0 (git version: e544780eb64a4a2557c1f51dde070b8d82b86c49)

Comment: curl -X GET localhost:1026/version -vv
* About to connect() to localhost port 1026 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Comment: Where are you doing the request from? Inside CentOS VM or from your VM host?

Comment: The service is running on my centos vm! However i tried the request both internal and external from another vm :/

Comment: If you are doing the curl request from an external VM, you cannot use `localhost` to access the Orion VM. In this case, you will have to configure the routes between the VMs, enabling the port forward if using NAT. From **inside the Orion VM**, try `curl localhost:1026/version` and put the message you get.

Comment: By the way... to upgrade your version, you need to run the command: `sudo yum install contextBroker`. This will update the Orion version.

Comment: I know but i had some problems at centos 7 with some required libraries that only exist at centos 6! Finally i followed the docker based installation and it worked! Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to install Orion is using Docker to test or study: (https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/orion/).

Docker and docker-compose. You install Orion and Mongodb together, in a quick time. (https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/tree/master/docker)

Have you tried using this method?
With it you can use the last stable version (1.10.0).

Comment: I finally did this and it works! Now i have version 1.10.0